# Shoud 'Technical difficulties' questions be considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

I really feel like basically any question in the [technical-support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) tag can be answered in a few steps.

1. Google the Error code, continue from there
2. Reinstall the game, or if is in Steam, check for corrupted files.
3. You are screwed, go check with technical support.

And since basically every question in that category can be answered in the same way, I really wonder, is it useful?

Because for Step 1, we could apply low effort. You got the error code BSW002 and didn't bother checking the error to see what it is? And for Step 3, it's basically that no help can be given on this forum, as much as we would like to.

So should the [technical-support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) tag be offtopic, or should trying to post a [technical-support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) question at least ask you if you have done the few basic "debugging a crashed game" steps before posting?

Comment: There are a lot more questions than just the "my game is crashing" in the technical-support tag. Sure, the error code ones are lower effort, but the entire tag is not at fault here.

Comment: It isn't always that simple, if you want to look at a technical-support question that was wonky but (sort of) solved check out mine here https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361582/224120

Answer (score 6):

**Technical support questions are absolutely on-topic here.**

It appears that the concept of downvotes and close votes are being conflated.

Technical support questions don't violate any of the rules listed in [what's on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There are also [plenty of awesome questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues?tab=Votes) using the [technical-support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) tag. Some of these questions are even at the top of Google search results!

I think what you're getting at is that many [technical-support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) questions don't show a lot of research effort. *This is exactly what downvotes are for.* If a given question is on-topic on Arqade but doesn't show any research effort, give it a downvote and move on.

Comment: I can't remember which tag on which site did that, but I remember at some point posting a question on a Stack Exchange and because I had one tag in particular, a warning popped up. Maybe we could look into if you try to post a [technical-support] question, a confirmation appears before posting the question about : Have you tried these? Or at least pushing for close questions that are just 'My game doesn't work, plz fix'